# Non-Numeric character found where a numeric was expected?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

I created an insert procedure with some constraints. Procedure created successfully but when I try to insert Im getting ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. Here is my code

```
 CREATE TABLE Customers
(
 IDNumber INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
 LastName VARCHAR(50),
 DOB DATE,
 Gender CHAR(10) 
 );

 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertCustomer (id IN Integer, firstName IN varchar, lastName IN varchar, dob IN date, gender varchar)
AS
 BEGIN
 If sysdate between to_date('monday 08:00 am') and to_date('monday 05:00 pm') 
or sysdate between to_date('tuesday 08:00 am') and to_date('tuesday 05:00 pm') 
or sysdate between to_date('wednesday 08:00 am') and to_date('wednesday 05:00 pm') 
or sysdate between to_date('thursday 08:00 am') and to_date('thursday 05:00 pm') 
or sysdate between to_date('friday 10:00 am') and to_date('friday 01:00 pm')  
 then 

INSERT INTO Customers values(id, firstName, lastName, dob, gender); 

  ELSE 
 raise_application_error(-20101, 'Can only insert during the week between normal business hours');
END if;
END insertCustomer
  ;
   /

   execute insertCustomer (18, 'Andre', 'Walker', '12-NOV-1993', 'male');
```

I've been stuck a while now. I'm sure in oracle that date format is correct. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `to_date('friday 10:00 am')` is almost certainly not valid and, if it were to work, almost certainly doesn't do what you want.  It might be valid if you happened to set your `nls_date_format` appropriately but then it's not going to resolve to the date I'm guessing you'd want it to resolve to.

Comment: so how would I fix the sp to resolve this

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.  I'm not sure why you are certain that the date format is correct-- that implies that you've changed your `nls_date_format` in a way that you haven't mentioned in your post.

Comment: if I just do a regular insert I have no problems but when executing the sp I get the error. I basically want the sp to check if the time is between 8am and 5am on weekdays if not display the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `INSERT INTO Customers values(id, firstName, lastName, dob, gender);` you are trying to insert the `dob` as char ('12-NOV-1993'), you need to change the insert value of dob to `INSERT INTO Customers values(id, firstName, lastName, TO_DATE(dob), gender);` and that should do the trick.

And also as pointed out before, your `to_date('monday 08:00 am')` is most certainly not correct and will result in "Julian date" errors.

This here is a different way to do what you have tried to do

```
  IF TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') IN (1,2,3,4) AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH:MI am') BETWEEN '08:00 am'  AND '05:00 pm' THEN
    INSERT...
  ELSIF TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 5 AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH:MI am') BETWEEN '10:00 am'  AND '01:00 pm' THEN
    INSERT...
  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
  END IF;
```

where the integers represent "day of the week" and the am in `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH:MI am')` changes to either pm or am automatically depending on the current value of sysdate.

Edit: Note that I am European and normally use the 24h format, so I have no idea how the am/pm will deal with this(only ran a small test before posting), that is up to you to test.